# Changing image "source" dynamically in runtime

Tags: apache-flex, image, embed

i am trying to modify during runtime an image in my application, this image is located inside assets folder, so thats why i dissable -use-network=false flag, then i call something like this:

```
img.source="../assets/pict.png";
```

but it's not working.
i know its a silly question but i am stuck here. any hint i appreciate.

Br

Comment: PS. Go accept some answers to your previous questions (and this one) Rep is the only thing we get for helping you, why deny us?

Comment: sorry, i didnt have time to reply that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the ".." all of my images are in my "img" folder and I call them with "/img/image.png"

Comment: the .. was because i got the picture folder at the same level than binary one, so move to the parent folder and enter in the imges one.

i discover that if i put the resource folder inside the binary one its working, otherwise is not. Maybe some security policy or something is affecting this.

anyway thanks for your help, i appreciate.